# not enough arguments for format string from excel to mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to put all information from excel to mysql, while processing it have these problem.
struggling to solve it!
counted all %s, seems like didn't miss any of them.

```
query = """INSERT INTO sanction (id, organization_type, organization, date, decision_number, penalty_type, penalty_way
                       penalty, violation, execution_period, article, note, type_npa, department, uploaded_date) 
                        VALUES(null, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""


for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    organization_type = sheet.cell(r,1).value
    organization = sheet.cell(r,2).value
    date = sheet.cell(r,3).value
    decision_number = sheet.cell(r,4).value
    penalty_type = sheet.cell(r,5).value
    penalty_way = sheet.cell(r,6).value
    penalty = sheet.cell(r,7).value
    violation = sheet.cell(r,8).value
    execution_period = sheet.cell(r,9).value
    article =sheet.cell(r,10).value
    note =sheet.cell(r,11).value
    type_npa =sheet.cell(r,12).value
    department =sheet.cell(r,13).value
    uploaded_date =datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") 


    values = (organization_type, organization, date, decision_number, penalty_type, 
                  penalty_way,penalty, violation, execution_period,article, note, type_npa, department,uploaded_date)


    mycursor.execute(query, [values])
```

Comment: For your next question, please add the full error stacktrace in the question, because  it contains valuable information to find the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice 2 things that could cause this error:

1. Your variable `values` is a `tuple` already, so you dont need to wrap it inside a new `list`.

   That means, change this line

   ```
   mycursor.execute(query, [values])
   ```

   to

   ```
   mycursor.execute(query, values)
   ```
2. You are also missing a comma in your query in the part where you list the target column names, between `penalty_way` and `penalty`.

---

In case of this many arguments, I would suggest to restructure your code so that you can more easily see if you missed anything.

For example, here is a version that groups the 15 parameters in a 1-3-3-3-3-2 formation in 3 parts: the first part of the query, the second part of the query and also when building the `values` tuple.

```
query = """
    INSERT INTO sanction (
        id,
        organization_type, organization, date,
        decision_number, penalty_type, penalty_way,
        penalty, violation, execution_period,
        article, note, type_npa,
        department, uploaded_date)
    VALUES (
        null,
        %s, %s, %s,
        %s, %s, %s,
        %s, %s, %s,
        %s, %s, %s,
        %s, %s)
"""

for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    organization_type = sheet.cell(r, 1).value
    organization = sheet.cell(r, 2).value
    date = sheet.cell(r, 3).value
    decision_number = sheet.cell(r, 4).value
    penalty_type = sheet.cell(r, 5).value
    penalty_way = sheet.cell(r, 6).value
    penalty = sheet.cell(r, 7).value
    violation = sheet.cell(r, 8).value
    execution_period = sheet.cell(r, 9).value
    article = sheet.cell(r, 10).value
    note = sheet.cell(r, 11).value
    type_npa = sheet.cell(r, 12).value
    department = sheet.cell(r, 13).value
    uploaded_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

    values = (
        # the first value of the INSERT statement will be NULL
        organization_type, organization, date,              # 3 elements
        decision_number, penalty_type, penalty_way,         # 3 elements
        penalty, violation, execution_period,               # 3 elements
        article, note, type_npa,                            # 3 elements
        department, uploaded_date,                          # 2 elements
    )
    mycursor.execute(query, values)
```